# llama model could not create sql queries with lang chain

Tags: python, langchain, llama, llama-cpp-python

I tried this llama model to replace ChatGPT for SQL QA.It got stuck on the SQL query generation part.is there a way to generate an output in the form of natural language same as ChatGPT?
(I installed llama-cpp-python ver. 0.1.78 to avoid some errors)

```
# pip install llama-cpp-python==0.1.78
model_path = 'model/orca-mini-3b.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin'


def load_model() -> LlamaCpp:
    callback: CallbackManager = CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()])
    llama_model: LlamaCpp = LlamaCpp(
        model_path=model_path,
        temperature=0,
        max_tokens=2000,
        top_p=1,
        callback_manager=callback,
        verbose=False,
        n_ctx=20000
    )
    return llama_model


llm = load_model()

db = SQLDatabase.from_uri("sqlite:///db.sqlite3")
db_chain = SQLDatabaseChain.from_llm(llm, db, verbose=True, use_query_checker=True)
try:
    ans = db_chain.run("""names of the table present in the database?""")
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    ans = 'I am offline'
print(ans)
```

Comment: could you post your queries and response from your model, and what is your expectation? ?

Comment: > Entering new SQLDatabaseChain chain...
what is the name of the most popular album?
SQLQuery:SELECT "Title" FROM "Album" ORDER BY "ArtistId" DESC LIMIT 1;
SQLResult: [('Koyaanisqatsi (Soundtrack from the Motion Picture)',)]
Answer:Koyaanisqatsi (Soundtrack from the Motion Picture)
> Finished chain.
question

Comment: this is the expected format of output , But this output is generated using chatgpt as llm. I replaced the llm with 'llama', as a chatbot it is working okay,but when it comes to sql QnA agent, llama stuck on '> Entering new SQLDatabaseChain chain...' and not providing any output.(not even any verbose)

Comment: Update your question with that